# Search utf-8 string with Gmail X-GM-RAW IMAP command

Tags: utf-8, gmail, imap, gmail-imap

Gmail's imap extension command X-GM-RAW allows me to perform a search if I use a ascii query string. If utf-8 chars are used in the query, the imap returns bad response.

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/imap_extensions#extension_of_the_search_command_x-gm-raw

How should the utf-8 input string be encoded so that X-GM-RAW search will work fine. I do not want to loose the flexibility to search specific field like "subject" or "rfc833msgid"

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Specify CHARSET UTF-8 and send the UTF-8 search term in a literal. For example, to search for 你好, which is 6 bytes long when encoded in UTF-8:

```
A SEARCH CHARSET UTF-8 X-GM-RAW {6}
+ go ahead
你好
* SEARCH 15
a OK SEARCH completed (Success)
```

In this example you would actually send the 6-byte UTF-8 encoding of 你好 on the third line.

This will work for any SEARCH keyword that accepts an astring, including SUBJECT and HEADER MESSAGE-ID.

Comment: I have tried this command to search non ascii character like Japanese..But i am getting "Bad command could not parse " error.I just sent the 6 byte UTF-8 encded string like the format \xE4\xBD\xA0\xE5\xA5\xBD.. But still i couldnt resolve thid issue..Please let me know encode string format

Answer (score 0):

IMAP isn't [8-bit clean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8-bit_clean), so it has to use a variety of different encodings to represent any 8-bit data.

For things like **folders and labels** IMAP4 uses **[Modified UTF-7](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-5.1.3)** to represent these characters.  Conveniently, ascii data encoded in modified utf7 encodes as itself, so normally nothing special needs to be done.

For message **headers** (including subjects) the text is encoded as **[Mime words](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Encoded-Word)**.

And finally **atttachments** are generally encoded as either **Base64** or **Quoted-Printable**

My best guess is that GMail uses modified utf7 for their X-GM-RAW queries.  The best reference implementation for modified utf7 I've found is in the [IMAPClient python library](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/IMAPClient/)

Hope this helps!